# 'Hyperplanning' vs 'emploi du temps'

Tags: usage, synonymes, travail

I have some questions regarding hyperplanning' and 'emploi du temps'.

- What are the differences, if any, between 'hyperplanning' et 'emploi du temps'?
- Can one use 'hyperplanning' colloquially (not necessarily in a professional context)?
- I have seen the spellings 'hyperplanning' et 'hyper-planning'. Which of them is more correct?
- What is the proper prononciation of 'hyperplanning'?

Comment: Pour ma part, je n'ai jamais entendu/lu hyperplanning en français.

Comment: @XouDo http://www.index-education.com/fr/presentation-hyperplanning.php

Comment: Isn't that just the name of a software?

Comment: Brand names should be written as spelled. Here it is: HYPERPLANNING, and it is not a term at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are the differences, if any, between 'hyperplanning' et 'emploi du temps'?

I had never heard about hyperplanning before. *Emploi du temps* is an established set expression in French. Hyperplanning is the name of a commercial software developed in France, targeting educational institutions and widely used there.

> Can one use 'hyperplanning' colloquially (not necessarily in a professional context)?

Probably only in the above-mentioned institutions.

> I have seen the spellings 'hyperplanning' et 'hyper-planning'. Which of them is more correct?

The [editor](http://www.index-education.com/fr/presentation-hyperplanning.php) mostly uses the all uppercase name **HYPERPLANNING** but there are a few instances of **Hyperplanning** which I would recommend, being the usual way proper names are written.

[image]

[image]

> What is the proper prononciation of 'hyperplanning'?

The French way: [ipɛʁplaniŋ]

Comment: Thanks you very much! Just one more question: Is it the acronym EDT (for emploi du temps) used outside a professional/academic context?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @Dimitris EDT won't easily be understood, but you can use the word _planning_